# PHP Redirect problem with subdomain

Tags: php, redirect

I'm using PHP to redirect a page back to the previous page with the following:

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

This set of pages will only be used by internal users, so I'm not terribly concerned about the fact that the referer will not always be available.

The problem I'm running in to is that if the referer looks like `http://subdomain.domain.com/test.php?id=13`, the redirect ends up going to `http://subdomain.domain.com/.domain.com/test.php?id=13`.  Notice the additional `.domain.com/` in the url.

I've tested by hardcoding the value, and it causes the problem as well.  `phpMyAdmin` seems to suffer the same issue, but only on this particular server.

If this is not an SO question, please move accordingly.

**EDIT**: per @yaggo

test.php contains only `header("Location: http://subdomain.domain.com/test2.php");`

```
curl --head --referer 'http://subdomain.domain.com/' 'http://subdomain.domain.com/test.php'

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/0.7.64
Date: Fri, 02 Apr 2010 17:21:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12-pl0-gentoo
Location: .domain.com/test2.php
```

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is sent by browser. Which browser you are using?

Comment: Chrome.  But I've already verified that the HTTP_REFERER value is correct, and complete.

Comment: why do you have braces around the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?

Comment: @Nexum That allows an array value to be treated as a variable in a string. You can't address an array element without braces.

Comment: When you say you hardcoded the value, what did you hardcode in?

Comment: Tim: Not true. `echo "$_GET[id]"` and the like work perfectly. You're just not allowed to use quoted keys in the array reference. This only works for 1-dimensional arrays though. PHP's parser isn't quite greedy enough and will treat `echo "$arr[0][1]"` as $arr[0] and plaintext [1]. That's when you have to use the braces.

Comment: @Josh - `http://subdomain.domain.com/test.php?id=13`

Comment: @Marc: Not using braces is very much frowned apon. Your code is looking for a constant called "id", just as if you wrote: `echo $_GET[id];` -- Not only will it generate an E_NOTICE, but if there *is* a constant called `id` then it's value will be used instead. *Always use braces for array access in quoted strings*.

Comment: @gms8994: That is very strange. I can't think of any reason why that hardcoded value would redirect anywhere else. Something else is probably at play. Got any `.htaccess` rewrite rules?

Comment: @Josh: No it's not, It works perfectly, with no errors. Try this: `error_report(E_ALL); define('id', 'blah'); $x = array('id' => 'yo', 'blah' => 'hahaha'; echo "$x[id]\n";`. You get 'yo', and no warnings/errors. Remember, constants only work OUTSIDE of strings. `define('const', 'text'); echo "const";` gets you 'text', not 'const'.

Comment: OK. I tested that and when in quotes, that does work as you say. I remember reading another comment on StackOverflow stating it wouldn't, but I was mistaken. It does, however, change meaning if removed from quotes. I still stand by the opinion that it's always best to use braces.

Comment: @Josh: No `.htaccess` that would be affecting this.

Comment: Can you show the full code of the redirect script please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your nginx configuration is causing the problems.

Its totally possible that nginx is modifying the response headers. This is not by default - you could have a configuration that is aimed for it to behave as a reverse proxy etc.

Have you tried testing the redirect on a nginx with its default configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I've recreated both your programs on my server
once with

```
header("Location: http://subdomain.domain.com/some/place");
```

and once with

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

and both give the corret result

```
curl --head --referer 'http://subdomain.domain.com/some/place' 'http://subdomain.domain.com/test.php'

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 02 Apr 2010 17:48:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.2
Location: http://subdomain.domain.com/some/place
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm using a different version of PHP and a different webserver, so there's two things to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] the redirect ends up going to http://subdomain.domain.com/.domain.com/test.php?id=13.

Can you isolate the problem a little bit more? Is that url exactly what is returned by PHP or  is it how browser (Chrome?) sees it?

Can you check the actual headers e.g. with curl:

```
$ curl --head --referer 'http://your-referer' 'http://your-page/'
```

Answer (score -2):

`header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

**Edited:**

Check you .htaccess settings or if no solution found u can use preg_replace to remove that last ".domain.com"

but it looks that is a not a php error.

OR use javascript to get the referer address...
then use window.location.href = url; to redirect ...

Comment: That does the exact same thing. how would this fix the problem.

Comment: actually he had curly brackets there so i thought sticking to the normal, spimple solution is best. but -1 is too harsh as this wasn't an incorrect answer.