# Is this the right way to set a cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies, redirect

// if login is ok then we add a cookie

```
         $_POST['user_name'] = stripslashes($_POST['user_name']); 

          $hour = time() + 3600; 

             setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['user_name'], $hour); 

            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);
```

Is this a right way to set cookies? Its been causing me serious redirect errors.  See here:  [PHP Redirect problem with subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501338/php-redirect-problem-with-subdomain)

Answer (score 5):

No, strings need to be quoted (use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get warnings about bad things like unquoted strings).

```
setcookie('ID_my_site', $_POST['user_name'], $hour);
setcookie('Key_my_site', $_POST['password'], $hour);
```

Besides that, if you have to apply `stripslashes()` to your GPC data, your server configuration is horrible. `magic_quotes_gpc` should be disabled. Also, only use stripslashes if `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is true. Otherwise you must not use stripslashes on GPC data.

Additionally, storing plaintext passwords in cookies is an **extremely bad thing**! While browsers usually encrypt stored passwords, cookies are not encrypted.

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate in detail what i need to do to fix the redirect and enhance the cookie process.

Answer (score 1):

Also, bear in mind that setting a cookie will not work if your script has done an output to the browser. So if you get a warning from a PHP line of code, the cookie won't be set. The following line can easily generate a warning:

```
$_POST['user_name'] = stripslashes($_POST['user_name']);
```

Make sure you check if the key exists in the $_POST array.

```
if (array_key_exists('user_name', $_POST))
```